# Is this selection sort or some other sorting algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

I am curious to know about this sorting algorithm. I coded it based on a very basic understanding of how selection sort would work but the code does not match selection sort.

```
public static int[] selectionSort(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
            int smallest = array[i];
            if (array[j] < smallest) {
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = smallest;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Is this just a bad version of selection sort or is it a different sorting algorithm? I have looked up pseudocodes of popular sorting algorithms and none match what I have here. Help appreciated.

Comment: That is Bubble Sort. More info: https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: @D.Kastier thanks for your help. I always mess up these sorting sorting algorithms. The only one I know for sure is Merge Sort.

Comment: You're welcome! Check this for yet more information: https://www.crio.do/blog/top-10-sorting-algorithms/

Comment: I think your programming would benefit from keeping your *understanding of what should be done how* with the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is [selection sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), not bubble sort. Bubble sort works by swapping adjacent elements. This is placing the smallest (remaining) value into the ith location each time through the outer loop, which is selection sort.

Comment: I am not sure if this is selection sort. I did a bit more research and selection sort initially selects the element at 0th index and then goes through the array to find an element smaller than the one located at 0th index. If such an element exists, this element becomes the new minimum, and the search continues. However, my code is not doing that. It seems like this code searches for a smallest element and swaps it with the current smallest right away. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-PGLbMth_g

Comment: @Iamlearningmath The inner loop is swapping right away, but by the time it has reached the end of the array, the effect is that it has found the smallest remaining element and sorted it to the ith position.